# Arduino LCD Space Invaders

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

This is an arduino code which needs help. There is a bug with my code that I couldn't figure out. I need help to put the aliens in an array.

This is the problem code---

```
#define ALIEN_COUNT 24
int yAliens[ALIEN_COUNT]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
int xAliens[ALIEN_COUNT] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

//...

for(byte a=0; a<=24; a++){
  if(fire&&xb== xAliens[a] && yb == yAliens[a]){
   hitAlien = true;
   break;
  }
  if(a>=25){
    a=0;
  }
}
 if (hitAlien) {
    fire = false;            //bullet stops moving
    lcd.setCursor(xb, yb);   //the position of the alien
    lcd.print(" ");          //becomes blank
    lcd.setCursor(xb+1,yb);
    lcd.print(" ");
}
```

This is the full code---

```
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
byte Ship[8] = { //the code for the player ship
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00001,
    B00111,
    B11001,
    B00111,
    B00001,
    B00000
};
byte Ailen[8] = {//the code for the aliens
    B10001,
    B10001,
    B01010,
    B01110,
    B01110,
    B01010,
    B10001,
    B10001
};
byte Bullet[8] = {//the code for the bullet
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B11111,
    B11111,
    B11011,
    B11111,
    B11111,
    B00000
};
int time = 0;//adds to make the bullet stop
int lButton = 13;//pin for the left button
int rButton = 6;//pin for the right button
int fButton = 7;//pin for the firing button
int lState = 0;//state of the left button
int rState = 0;//state of the right button
int fState = 0;//state of the firing button
int xb = 0;//the bullets x coords
int yb = 0;//the bullets y coords
int xa = 0;//the aliens x coords
int ya = 0;//the aliens y coords
int xShip=15;//the starting x coord of the ship
int yShip=0;//starting y coord of the ship
int xAilens[2] = {0,1};
int yAilens[12]= {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}; /* attempted use of the array
                                                 which did not work but I will leave it in*/
boolean ailen = true;//is the one ailen alive?
boolean fire = false;//is the bullet firing
const int dTime= 150;//what is the delay for movement
void setup() {
    pinMode(lButton, INPUT);//sets up left button
    pinMode(rButton, INPUT);//sets up right button
    pinMode(fButton, INPUT);//sets up firing button
    lcd.begin(16, 2);//parameter of the lcd
    lcd.createChar(0, Ship);//sets char
    lcd.createChar(1,Ailen);//sets char
    lcd.createChar(2,Bullet);//sets char
    lcd.setCursor(xa,ya);//coords of the one alien
    lcd.write((byte)1);//prints the one alien
}
void loop() {
    lState=digitalRead(lButton);//pulls the state of the left button
    rState=digitalRead(rButton);//pulls the state of the right button
    fState=digitalRead(fButton);//pulls the state of the firing button
    xb = xShip;
    if(fire==true&&yb==ya&&xb==xa&&ailen==true){/*if the bullet is moving
                                                  and the alien's position is the same as the bullets, then*/
        fire=false;//bullet stops moving
        ailen=false;//the alien is dead
        lcd.setCursor(xa,ya);//the position of the alien
        lcd.print(" ");//becomes blank
        tone(9,400,100);//plays kill noise
    }
    if(fire==true&&time<17){//if the bullet is moving and is on the screen then
        xb = xb-time;//the bullet is time further away than the spaceship
        lcd.setCursor(xb-1,yb);//fires one away from ship not on ship
        lcd.write((byte)2);//displays bullet
        lcd.setCursor(xb+1,yb);//clears where bullet was
        lcd.print(" ");//clear symbol
        time++;//increase time
        delay(dTime/2);//bullet moves twice as fast as ship
    }

    if(fire==true&&time>=17){//if the bullet is still moving offscreen then

        fire=false;//stop moving the bullet
        time=0;//reset the time for next time a bullet is fired
    }
    else if(fState==HIGH&&fire==false){//if the fire button is pressed
        fire=true;//starts moving the bullet
        yb=yShip;//makes the bullet move where the ship was not where is always is
    }

    if(rState==HIGH&&lState==LOW){//if the right button is pressed and the left isn't
        yShip=0;//make the ship move to the right if already on right, nothing happens
        lcd.setCursor(xShip,yShip);//ship's location
        lcd.write((byte)0);//display the ship byte
        lcd.setCursor(xShip,yShip+1);//clear where the ship was
        lcd.print(" ");//clearing block
        delay(dTime);//time to deter mashing
    }

    else if(lState==HIGH&&rState==LOW){// if the right button is pressed and the right isn't
        yShip=1;//make the ship on the left of the screen, if on left, nothing happens
        lcd.setCursor(xShip,yShip);//coorinates for the ship's location
        lcd.write((byte)0);//displays the ship
        lcd.setCursor(xShip,yShip-1);//clears where the ship was
        lcd.print(" ");//clearing block
        delay(dTime);//time to deter mashing
    }

    else{//if nothing is pressed
        lcd.setCursor(xShip,yShip);//set previous coordinates for the ship*good practice
        lcd.write((byte)0);//display the ship
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `xb = xShip;`, you never update `xShip`

Comment: You don't need `time` just detect when bullet is out of screen, `xb = xShip;` shloud be put where you set `fire` to `true` and `yb` to `yship`

Comment: One more thing, how would I put all of the aliens as an array?

Comment: There was an bug that caused the bullet to continue printing itself across the screen after an certain point thus, I added this to the code

Comment: 'if (fire) {        //if the bullet is moving and is on the screen then    
      lcd.setCursor(xb+1,yb);//clears where bullet was 
      lcd.print(" ");//clear symbol 
      if (xb-- < 0||time>15) {//move the bullet 
       /* bullet ouside of the screen */ 
       fire = false; 
       } else if(time<=15) { 
       lcd.setCursor(xb, yb); 
       lcd.write((byte)2);       //displays bullet 
       delay(DTIME / 2);//bullet moves twice as fast as ship 
        time++;
        } 
        } ' Sorry the code did not format in the comment. @Ôrel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to simplify our code and fix your problem
I can't test it, so I can't be sure everything is good
I use `byte` instead of `int` for memory footprint consideration
I have removed `time` and directly deal with the bullet position
To be easier to understand I delete old position, update position and print the object in the new position.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);                                        
byte Ship[8] = { //the code for the player ship                               
    B00000, 
    B00000,                                                                   
    B00001, 
    B00111, 
    B11001, 
    B00111, 
    B00001, 
    B00000 
}; 
byte Ailen[8] = {//the code for the ailens                                    
    B10001, 
    B10001, 
    B01010, 
    B01110,                                                                   
    B01110, 
    B01010, 
    B10001, 
    B10001 
}; 
byte Bullet[8] = {//the code for the bullet                                   
    B00000, 
    B00000, 
    B11111,                                                                   
    B11111, 
    B11011,                                                                   
    B11111, 
    B11111,                                                                   
    B00000                                                                    
}; 
#define lButton  13 //pin for the left button                                 
#define rButton  6  //pin for the right button                                
#define fButton  7  //pin for the firing button 
int xa = 0;//the aliens x coords 
int ya = 0;//the aliens y coords                                              
int xShip=15;//the starting x coord of the ship                               
int yShip=0;//starting y coord of the ship                                    
int xAilens[2] = {0,1};                                                       
int yAilens[12]= {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}; /* attempted use of the array   
                                                 which did not work but I will leave it in*/              
#define DTIME 150 //what is the delay for movement                            
void setup() {                                                                
    pinMode(lButton, INPUT);//sets up left button                             
    pinMode(rButton, INPUT);//sets up right button                            
    pinMode(fButton, INPUT);//sets up firing button                           
    lcd.begin(16, 2);//parameter of the lcd 
    lcd.createChar(0, Ship);//sets char                                       
    lcd.createChar(1, Ailen);//sets char                                      
    lcd.createChar(2, Bullet);//sets char                                     
    lcd.setCursor(xa,ya);//coords of the one ailen                            
    lcd.write((byte)1);//prints the one ailen                                 
} 

void loop() { 
    static boolean ailen = true;   //is the one ailen alive?                  
    static boolean fire = false;   //is the bullet firing                     
    static byte xb = 0;             //the bullets x coords                     
    static byte yb = 0;             //the bullets y coords                     

    byte lState = digitalRead(lButton);  //pulls the state of the left button  
    byte rState = digitalRead(rButton);  //pulls the state of the right button 
    byte fState = digitalRead(fButton);  //pulls the state of the firing button                            


    /*if the bullet is moving and the alien's position is                     
     * the same as the bullets, then                                          
     * */  
    if (fire && ailen && yb == ya && xb == xa) {                              
        fire = false;            //bullet stops moving                        
        ailen = false;           //the alien is dead                          
        lcd.setCursor(xa, ya);   //the position of the alien                  
        lcd.print(" ");          //becomes blank                              
        tone(9,400,100);         //plays kill noise                           
    } 
    if (fire) {        //if the bullet is moving and is on the screen then    
        lcd.setCursor(xb1,yb);//clears where bullet was 
        lcd.print(" ");//clear symbol 
        if (xb-- < 0) {//move the bullet 
            /* bullet ouside of the screen */ 
            fire = false; 
        } else { 
            lcd.setCursor(xb, yb); 
            lcd.write((byte)2);       //displays bullet 
            delay(DTIME / 2);//bullet moves twice as fast as ship 
        } 
    } 

    if (fState == HIGH && !fire) {  //if the fire button is pressed 
        fire = true;                     //starts moving the bullet 
        /* bullet starts one away from ship */ 
        xb = xShip - 1; 
        yb = yShip; 
    } 

    //if the right button is pressed and the left isnt 
    if (rState == HIGH && lState == LOW && yShip != 0) { 
        lcd.setCursor(xShip, yShip);  //ship's location 
        lcd.print(" ");               //clearing block 
        yShip = 0;                    //make the ship move to the right 
        lcd.setCursor(xShip, yShip);  //ship's location 
        lcd.write((byte)0);           //display the ship byte 
        delay(DTIME);                 //time to deter mashing 
    } 
    // if the right button is pressed and the     right isnt 
    else if (lState == HIGH && rState == LOW && yShip != 1) { 
        lcd.setCursor(xShip, yShip);  //ship's location 
        lcd.print(" ");               //clearing block 
        yShip = 1;                    //make the ship move to the right 
        lcd.setCursor(xShip, yShip);  //ship's location 
        lcd.write((byte)0);           //display the ship byte 
        delay(DTIME);                 //time to deter mashing 
    } 
    //if nothing is pressed 
    else{ 
        lcd.setCursor(xShip, yShip);//set previous coordinates for the ship*good practice 
        lcd.write((byte)0);//display the ship 
    } 

}
```

Comment: This works just as I needed it to. Thanks so much- Ben